# php - Como definir tempo máximo de execução, usando intervalo em cada loop?

Tags: php, mysql

Bom dia!
Preciso enviar alguns e-mail lembretes de acordo com algumas condições. Montei um script que consulta as informações na base de dados (MySQL) e dispara os e-mails. O script está funcionando muito bem, porém, pelo que vi em alguns fóruns pela internet, é interessante setar um intervalo entre o envio de um e-mail e outro. Coloquei intervalo de 20 segundos entre após cada envio, mas antes disso defini um tempo máximo de execução do script, e pelo que vi quando uso a função  `set_time_limit()` a função `sleep()` é ignorada.

Segue a lógica do meu script abaixo:

```
// faço a consulta na base de dados (MySQL)
if ($stmt->rowCount() > 0) {
   $result = $stmt->fetchAll();
} else {
   exit;
}

// controlar tempo máximo de execução do script
$qtd_email =  $stmt->rowCount();
$time_email = 20;
$segundos = ($qtd_email * $time_email) + 20; // adiciono 20 seg de folga
set_time_limit($segundos);

foreach ($result as $rs):

   // mensagem do e-mail

   // envia o e-mail

   // Ao terminar 1° loop, aguarda 20 segundos para o próximo
   sleep($time_email);

endforeach;
```

Nesse caso a função `sleep()` está sendo ignorada. O tempo de execução do script no servidor que vou hospedar a aplicação é de no máximo 60 segundos, por isso preciso usar `set_time_limit()`. Caso alguém souber uma maneira de contornar isso, fico muito grato!

Se houver uma outra forma de fazer, também estou aberto a sugestões. Grato desde já!

Comment: Não sei se entendi muito bem, você quer limitar o tempo de cada loop? E se não der tempo faz o que? Se tem vários registros faz o que?

Comment: Isso, limitar o tempo de cada loop. Exemplo: terminou um loop, aguarda 20seg e começa o próximo. Vai dar tempo sim, note que defino o tempo limite de execução do script de acordo com a quantidade de registros na variável $qtd_email. Meu problema é que o PHP ignora a função sleep() quando uso set_time_limit().

Comment: Você está executando pela linha de comando? Tem vários posts aqui que tratam do assunto, a maior parte se refere a automatizar via crontab, eu já sugeri uso do sleep mas esse tipo de tarefa nunca deve passar por um servidor de páginas.

Comment: Vou usar o agendador de tarefas Cron para executar um arquivo PHP.

Comment: Preste atenção nas observações lá, tem umas dicas legais, mas qq duvida avise aqui